# Can you register an app in the "long press power button" menu?

Tags: android

On Android phones, there is a menu if you long-press the power button. There you can switch the phone off, put it into mute or airplane mode.

Is it possible to have your app register an option in that menu?

Comment: AFAIK, no, as that "menu" is device-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant.
You can only customize it with a custom ROM(or a modification), because its a part of the actual ROM you are using.

Custom roms like CyanogenMod, add options on this Power Menu(Extended Power menu) for:

> Reboot 
> .Regular 
> .Recovery 
> .Bootloader 
> Screenshot
>   
> Profiles

and more..

So, its only possible if you install an app, in your own Custom ROM/Mod, in which you make an entry for your application in the Power Menu. You can find flashable zips for that, and mimic the way of doing it, but consider that user must not only use your app, but install your Mod(that you have to make) also!

A tutorial to modify this menu, can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1169443), but can be tricky.

*Also a mod(that I mentioned), is a flashable zip, that can be install using Recovery, or a script that needs root access, and it changes specific parts of a ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. Though probably not without root.

1. The Xposed module, Advanced Power Menu+ can do it. [Link](http://repo.xposed.info/module/hk.kennethso168.xposed.apmplus).
2. [ButtonRemaper](http://www.xda-developers.com/buttonremaper-for-android/) can do it.